# Sort x-axis based on the date as index in Python chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

Although similar question has been answered but not sure why even I follow the solutions still my dates on the x-axis are not sorted. Please see the code below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import statistics
#import numpy as np


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=DB_RED;'
                  'Database=ANALYSIS;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from USER_AV_ED_6hr_target_Daily_SPC')

for row in cursor:
 print(row)

# Import ED data into a dataframe
df_ED_lastMonth= pd.read_sql_query(
'''select * from dbo.USER_AV_ED_6hr_target_Daily_SPC''', conn)
df_ED_lastMonth.head()

df_ED_lastMonth['ED_diff']=df_ED_lastMonth['ED_6hr_Compliant%'].diff()
df_ED_lastMonth['ED_diff'] = abs(df_ED_lastMonth['ED_diff'])

print(df_ED_lastMonth.head())



#The average moving range and the average of the last 300 measurements

df_ED_lastMonth['X_men'] = df_ED_lastMonth['ED_6hr_Compliant%'].tail(300).mean(axis=0)
df_ED_lastMonth['R_men'] = df_ED_lastMonth['ED_diff'].tail(300).mean(axis=0)
df_ED_lastMonth['UCLr'] = 3.27 * df_ED_lastMonth['R_men']
df_ED_lastMonth['UCLx'] = df_ED_lastMonth['X_men'] + (2.66*df_ED_lastMonth['R_men'])
df_ED_lastMonth['LCLx'] = df_ED_lastMonth['X_men'] - (2.66*df_ED_lastMonth['R_men'])
df_ED_lastMonth.head()

#Standard deviation for the process

df_ED_lastMonth['std_T'] = df_ED_lastMonth['R_men']/1.128
df_ED_lastMonth.tail(2)

df_ED_lastMonth.set_index('departure_ED_ADU', inplace=True)

fig1, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1,figsize=(18, 8))

plt.title('ED 6 hr Compliant%-Control Chart I-MR (July 2021)', color='darkblue')
plt.plot(df_ED_lastMonth['X_men'],color='green', alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(df_ED_lastMonth['UCLx'],color='red', alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(df_ED_lastMonth['LCLx'],color='red', alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(df_ED_lastMonth['ED_6hr_Compliant%'],color='blue', alpha=0.8)
plt.legend(loc=(0.65, 0.8))
plt.xlabel('Departure ED_ADU Date')
plt.ylabel('Compliant%')
#plt.xticks( 'departure_ED_ADU' )
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
#fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
plt.grid(True)
#plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 16
```

I am pulling data from SQL server, the 'departure_ED_ADU' in SQL is date format and then I have made it as an index. But in the plot the x-axis is not sorted. Could someone please let me know how to fix this keeping the same style rather than defining arrays for date and then loop through them? Thanks.

Comment: Check `df_ED_lastMonth.info()` to make sure the date column is a datetime dtype. If it is, and the values aren't sorted, then use `df_ED_lastMonth.sort_index(inplace=True)`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Interestingly, even if it was not a datetime format still worked. Thanks.